# How can I check if an image style for an image has been created already?

Tags: 7, media

Is there a function I can use to check if a particular image style for a given image has been created already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find one in the core files but fortunately it's pretty straightforward to implement:

```
function image_style_path_exists($style_name, $path) {
  $uri = image_style_path($style_name, $path);
  return file_exists($uri);
}
```

Assuming you have a file object you would call it like this:

```
$image_exists = image_style_path_exists('thumbnail', $file->uri);
```

If you only need to use it once in the site you could boil it down to:

```
$image_exists = file_exists(image_style_path('thumbnail', $file->uri));
```

but it's usually better to separate this sort of thing out into a function

Comment: it's a shame that drupal doesn't store this information in the database. These file checks are way too slow when checking 1000's of images for derivatives.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question has been answered but it doesn't seem that the answer handles image styles that have yet to be generated.

The following function tries to load an image style, which is independent of file generation. Then it checks to see if the file has been created, if it hasn't then we kick off the generating the actual image style image.

This hasn't been fully tested but initial tests seem to work nicely.

```
// $style = image style name
// $src = file URI
function _helper_image_style_exists($style, $src) {
  $image_style = image_style_load($style, $src);

  if(empty($image_style)) {
    return false;
  }

  //Check if image style image has been created yet
  $dest = image_style_path($style, $src);
  if(!file_exists($dest)) {
    // Create image from image style
    image_style_create_derivative($image_style, $src, $dest);
  }

  return $dest;
}
```

Comment: What an awesome solution, thanks! Just add a comment in there that $style = image style name and $src = file URI.

Comment: Why does file_exists() understand Drupal's public://? There is an explanation https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2012-06-14/file_exists-and-drupal-file-uri-how